# Will the rocks regenerate over time?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In Animal Crossing New Leaf there are rocks. I smacked one with a hammer and it crumbled leaving behind some Sapphire. I am wondering if these are one time finds as I have never seen them before.. Will the rocks slowly regenerate in AC:NL like the fossils and such??

In further investigation, only one rock broke. One dropped some coins the rest I just bounced my shovel off of.. That still leaves me with the question of if the ones the I can get the Sapphires out of will regenerate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rocks that have gems in them aren't actually part of your normal rocks. Every day there is a new rock out of place that you can smash for a gem. You're not actually "down" any rocks when you break it, and knowing which rocks are out of place is a good way to tell which has the gem.

Comment: Ah, that combined with the extra info I found out by smacking more rocks makes a bit of sense. I will keep an eye out for these!